# Need help understanding Django authentication code

Tags: python, django

Code from **views.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required 

@login_required
def index(request):
    user = request.user 
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user)
```

I can't understand the inline `@login_required`. Why should we use this decorator?

And what about `user = request.user`? In this project, we hadn't created a model named `user`.

Please explain this to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> In this code I can't understand inline @login_required Why should we use the decorator

The `@login_required` decorator does exactly what it says: it requires a user to log in when accessing the route associated with this view.

> And user=request.user user ?? In this project, we hadn't created models named user.

Django defines a `User` model fore you.

For more details about the default authentication and authorization system, [read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/). Googling something like "django login_required" gives a wealth of information.

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind this function is to achieve that only the logged-in user has access to the posts he wrote himself: all http requests contain the id of the user: if he is not logged in, he is identified as anonymous, otherwise as user.
To get his identification, you call request.user and then pass it to the query to call his posts.
Therefore :
neither an anonymous user nor another user can get access to the full list of posts of a third user.